# TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirm' of undefined react-redux-toastr

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some JavaScript code that gives this error is about "react-redux-toastr" package.

The code is as follow:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirm' of undefined`

Also the package.json file is as follow:

`"react-redux-toastr": "^7.4.9",`

How i can solve it ?

Comment: Please add the part of your code your referring to, for people to better understand what your problem might be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is about 'react-redux-tostr' version and you need to change its value in package.json file to "7.5.2" version.
Search in package.json file to find 'react-redux-toastr' and change its value to:

`"react-redux-toastr": "7.5.2"`

it will fix your problem.